# What does GCC visibility hidden do in those cases?

Tags: gcc, dll, shared-libraries, ld, dllexport

I am writing a library: some of the symbols are to be used by the user, and some other are internal cooking. I started using the visibility attribute following [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) of the GCC wiki, but I can’t quite figure what the attribute does in certain cases:

```
#define TATO_SYM_INTERNAL __attribute__((visibility("internal")))
#define TATO_SYM_PUBLIC __attribute__((visibility("default")))

struct linkset
{
public:
    typedef sentence::id      *     iterator;
    typedef const sentence::id   *  const_iterator;

    TATO_SYM_PUBLIC    linkset() ;
    TATO_SYM_INTERNAL  void allocate( const datainfo & _datainfo );
    TATO_SYM_PUBLIC    void addLink( sentence::id _a, sentence::id _b );
    TATO_SYM_PUBLIC    bool areLinked( sentence::id _a, sentence::id _b ) const;
    TATO_SYM_PUBLIC    std::pair<const_iterator, const_iterator> getLinksOf( sentence::id _a ) const;

private:
    typedef std::vector<sentence::id> linksArray;
    linksArray                                  m_links;
    std::vector< std::pair<size_t, size_t> >    m_offsets;

private:
    TATO_SYM_INTERNAL linkset( const linkset & ) = delete;
    TATO_SYM_INTERNAL linkset & operator=( const linkset & ) = delete;
};

inline
void linkset::addLink( sentence::id _a, sentence::id _b ) TATO_RESTRICT
{
  // internal stuff
}
```

First, there is no reason for the user to call `allocate()`. The member function is not documented, and it is only here for my pleasure. Does that make sense, in that case, to hide the symbol?

Second, `m_links` and `m_offsets`. If I added an attribute of visibility to them, what would it mean? Said differently, what does GCC do when I add `TATO_SYM_INTERNAL` to m_links?

Third, does it mean anything at all to hide the visibility of deleted member functions?

Answer (score 1):

First, `internal` visibility is [slightly dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421487/1836596). Consider using `hidden` visibility instead, which safer.

The visibility flags determine whether or not the linker can see a symbol. If somebody outside your library tries to call the `allocate` method, they will receive a linker error as if the method simply hasn't been implemented. This may be fine if you really don't want outsiders to call the method, but linker errors are generally more confusing than compiler errors. It may be better to mark the method as "private" (if possible), which will give your users a better error-message experience.

Since `m_links` and `m_offsets` are already private, there is no way for outside code to get to them. More importantly, they don't have linker symbols, so there is nothing to hide. Applying this attribute will have no effect.

The same is true for deleted member functions like your copy constructor. The functions aren't implemented anywhere (they can't be), so they don't have linker symbols, so the visibility attributes do nothing.