# GCC: In what way is visibility internal "pretty useless in real world usage"?

Tags: gcc, export, visibility, symbols

I am currently developing a library for QNX (x86) using GCC, and I want to make some symbols which are used exclusively in the library and are invisible to other modules, notably to the code which uses the library.

This works already, but, while doing the research how to achieve it, I have found a very worrying passage in GCC's documentation (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options, explanation for flag -fvisibility):

> Despite the nomenclature, default always means public; i.e., available
>   to be linked against from outside the shared object. protected and
>   internal are pretty useless in real-world usage so the only other
>   commonly used option is hidden. The default if -fvisibility isn't
>   specified is default, i.e., make every symbol public—this causes the
>   same behavior as previous versions of GCC.

I am very interested in how visibility "internal" is pretty useless in real-world-usage. From what I have understood from another passage from GCC's documentation (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes, explanation of the visibility attribute), visibility "internal" is even stronger (more useful for me) than visibility "hidden":

> Internal visibility is like hidden visibility, but with additional
>   processor specific semantics. Unless otherwise specified by the psABI,
>   GCC defines internal visibility to mean that a function is never
>   called from another module. Compare this with hidden functions which,
>   while they cannot be referenced directly by other modules, can be
>   referenced indirectly via function pointers. By indicating that a
>   function cannot be called from outside the module, GCC may for
>   instance omit the load of a PIC register since it is known that the
>   calling function loaded the correct value.

Could anybody explain in depth?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you just want to hide your internal symbols, just use `-fvisibility=hidden`. It does exactly what you want.

The `internal` flag goes much further than the `hidden` flag. It tells the compiler that ABI compatibility isn't important, since nobody outside the module will ever use the function. If some outside code does manage to call the function, it will probably crash.

Unfortunately, there are plenty of ways to accidentally expose `internal` functions to the outside world, including function pointers and C++ virtual methods. Plenty of libraries use callbacks to signal events, for example. If your program uses one of these libraries, you must never use an `internal` function as the callback. If you do, the compiler and linker won't notice anything wrong, and your program will have subtle, hard-to-debug crash bugs.

Even if your program doesn't use function pointers now, it might start using them years down the road when everyone (including you) has forgotten about this restriction. Sacrificing safety for tiny performance gains is usually a bad idea, so `internal` visibility is not a recommended project-wide default.

The `internal` visibility is more useful if you have some heavily-used code that you are trying to optimize. You can mark those few specific functions with `__attribute__ ((visibility ("internal")))`, which tells the compiler that speed is more important than compatibility. You should also leave a comment for yourself, so you remember to never take a pointer to these functions.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I think I had misunderstood the documentation I have cited in my first post. I had got the impression that there could be some way to get a pointer to a hidden function from other modules and that internal in this sense would be stronger than hidden when it comes to hiding the respective function from the outside world. I think I've got it now. Besides that, calling internal useless is a bit worrying; if it were, why should it be supported?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide in-depth answer, but I think that "internal" might be unpractical because it is processor dependent. You might get expected behaviour on some systems, but on others you get only "hidden".